# Crystal Reports, Maximum of current record subtracted from minimum of next record

Tags: crystal-reports, max, crystal-reports-2008, min

I'm working on a report that monitors the downtime of jobs in between different sections of my manufacturing companies floor.
Here's an example of what I have to work with:

SHR  - -   Minimum(Start Time)  - -    Maximum(End Time)
PUN  - -   Minimum(Start Time)  - -    Maximum(End Time) 
BEN  - -   Minimum(Start Time)  - -    Maximum(End Time)
MTP  - -   Minimum(Start Time)  - -    Maximum(End Time)
WLD  - -   Minimum(Start Time)  - -    Maximum(End Time) 
ASM  - -   Minimum(Start Time)  - -    Maximum(End Time)
Next what I want to do, is subtract the Maximum(end Time) of SHR from the Minimum(start TIme) of Pun, and then go all the way down, PUN from BEN, BEN from MTP etc.

Any pointers for a formula or sql query.  Thanks!! 

**Edit**
Here's an example of some code i've been trying. 
The issue I face is that there are multiple actual end times and actual beginning times per a process ID so i have to clarify the adjustment between processID 
***global datetimevar great; 
 great := Maximum ({TimecardLines.lmlActualEndTime}, {JobOperations.jmoProcessID}); 
 global datetimevar least; 
next({JobOperations.jmoProcessID}); 
 least := minimum({TimecardLines.lmlActualstartTime}, {JobOperations.jmoProcessID}); 
 global timevar getterdone; 
 least - great***

Comment: global datetimevar great; 
 <br/>
great := Maximum ({TimecardLines.lmlActualEndTime}, {JobOperations.jmoProcessID}); <br/>

global datetimevar least; next({JobOperations.jmoProcessID}); <br/>

least := minimum({TimecardLines.lmlActualstartTime}, {JobOperations.jmoProcessID}); <br/>

global timevar getterdone;  <br/>

least - great <br/>

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea; just pass the maximum value per group along via a global variable. Assuming your report is grouped by {JobOperations.jmoProcessID}, then you can do:

```
// Place this formula in Group Footer
whileprintingrecords;
datetimevar latest := maximum({TimecardLines.lmlActualEndTime}, JobOperations.jmoProcessID});

// You can place this formula anywhere in your group as long as it is BEFORE the placement of the previous formula (otherwise the 'latest' variable won't represent the previous group
// Suppress this formula for the first group, as it will not be applicable
whileprintingrecords;
datetimevar latest;

datediff('d', latest, minimum({TimecardLines.lmlActualEndTime}, JobOperations.jmoProcessID})
```